# $24$ items randomly placed in $4$ groups

Tags: combinatorics

I have $24$ items randomly divided into $4$ groups (it can happen that group has $0$ items). How can I prove that when I remove a maximum of $12$ items (of my choice) three boxes will have the same amount?

Comment: There could be $3$, $4$, $5$, and $6$ items  remaining in the four boxes.

Comment: 0 3 10 11 i think

Comment: "A maximum of 12"? So you could possibly remove zero, and the statement would still be true? Aside from Christian's counterexample, I feel the requirement of a maximum is a bit worthless. Do you mean a minimum?

Comment: consider example: 0 0 0 24 ; amount needed to take n=0, match condition $0 \leq n \leq 12$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W.l.o.g., any counter example could be written as $a,b,c,d$ where:

1. $a \leq b \leq c \leq d$,
2. $a + b + c + d = 24$
3. $a = 0$, because for any counter example $a,b,c,d$, we have another counter example $0, b, c, d+a$
4. $b + c \geq 13$, at least 13 items must be removed for case $0,0,0,x$
5. $d - b + c - b \geq 13$ for case $x,b,b,b$
6. From 2. and 5. we have $a + b + c + d - (d - b + c - b) = a + 3b \leq 11$, with 3. we have $3b \leq 11$, so $b \in \{0,1,2,3\}$
7. With 4. we know $c \geq 10$
8. This already gives solution $0,3,10,11.$ Continue to find different solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The conjecture is false, there are two counterexamples:

$$0, 3, 10, 11$$

and

$$0, 2, 11, 11$$